# How to query unique values of a field in grafana with lucene query editor for elasticsearch datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I have a grafana dashboard panel with the datasource of an elasticsearch index. In my ES index, I have the following fields: Timestamp, Key, Message.

I want it in a Table so I select Table from the dashboard visualizations options menu.

Next from the query box below the table, I select logs or raw data as the metric option. In the Query box it prepoulates with "lucece query". From here how do I query the index so the table only shows unique values?

Since I have many duplicates of keys that have different messages, I just want to visualize in this table the unique/distinct keys. I have tried various querys shown on SO using term aggregation but grafana errors out when given it.

For example i have tried :

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "unique_keys" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "key", "size":10000 }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}'
```

Grafana shows no data, even when there is supposed to be 50+unique keys from a total pool of 600 logs records.

I have also read that lucene query is not capable of this type of data search, so what are my options?